# stristr, if string contains nothing (empty string)

Tags: php, string, foreach, contains, isset

I'm making a search thing for my website, and when a particular parameter is '' (nothing), I want to display all the results. I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
<?php
$a = file("test.txt");
sort($a);
foreach ($a as $b) {
$c = explode("|", $b);
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    if (stristr($c[0], $_GET['name'])) {
        echo '<option value="' . $c[0] . '">' . $c[0] . '</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

And this is just a test script, I'm going to use multiple GETs in the above if statement.

Comment: You should really use more proper variable names instead of `$a` `$b` and `$c`. use `$file` `$line` and `$separated_line` for example.

Comment: When do you want to do what? If it's set and if it's empty?

Answer (score 2):

Use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead of isset.

Answer (score 1):

Check if stristr is not returning false..

```
if (stristr($c[0], $_GET['name']) != FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($_GET['name'])){
    echo '<option value="'.$c[0].'">'.$c[0].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = file("test.txt");
sort($a);
foreach ($a as $b) {
$c = explode("|", $b);
    if ((isset($_GET['name']) && stristr($c[0], $_GET['name'])) || !isset($_GET['name']))
        echo '<option value="' . $c[0] . '">' . $c[0] . '</option>';
```